A proof that all segments are equal. How can this be?
Take two segments of different lengths, say $AB$ and $CD$.

From an arbitrary ray starting at a point $A$ that is not $AB$, construct a segment $CD$.

Connect two points which are not connected.

Now, through each point of the longer line, construct a line parallel to the last constructed line. I pick a few points to demonstrate that.

Now, observe that any parallel line passing through the larger segment, also passes through the smaller one, so for each distinct point of the larger segment there exists a corresponding point in the smaller segment, and all these points are distinct. Therefore these segments are, in fact, equal. Therefore, all segments are equal.
What is wrong with this proof?

"Therefore these segments are, in fact, equal", why?

The ratio for any pair of little segments is the same as for the original segments which are indeed not equal.

You are basing equality on the existence of a bijection from one set to another.  That is only valid if the sets each have a finite number of elements.  A line segment has an infinite number of points.

The two segments can be composed of an equal number of sub segments each.  Nothing here requires sub segments of $AB$ to be equal to sub segments of $CD$.

There is a flaw in the reasoning that correspondence & equality are the same thing which they are not. All points on one side have a corresponding point on the opposite side but we can clearly see and prove that the lengths are not equal.

I guess this is objection to defining segment's length as 'a number of points it has'?

@Rusurano It would be, if anyone were proposing that as a definition of length.

The error is to say that two segments that have the same number of points are equal. It is well known that you cannot have a bijection between a finite set $A$ and one of its strict subsets $B$ ($B\subsetneq A$), because $\left|B\right|<\left|A\right|$. But as soon as the $A$ is infinite this is no longer true.
For example $\Bbb N^*=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ is a strict subset of $\Bbb N$, and the $f$ function defined as:
$$\begin{aligned}
f:&\Bbb N\to\Bbb {N^*}\\&n\mapsto n+1
\end{aligned}$$
is a bijection. This one is known as Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel.
Your demonstration is close to telling that $2=1$ because the function $f$ defined on $[0;1]$ by $f(x)=2x$ is a bijection from $[0; 1]$ to $[0; 2]$.

The number of elements of a set is called cardinality. You are right on one point: all segments of a plane have same cardinality, which is also the cardinality of any infinite line and is even equal to the cardinality of any surface and the cardinality of the full plane (welcome to the world of the transfinite cardinals ;-) ).
But the length of a segment is a quite different animal...

While these observations are relative to the problem, I think the more direct fallacy is that two sets having the same cardinailty is unrelated to having the same length (or measure under any other measure), because length is an additional structure to put on sets beyond their cardinality.

@GregMartin: this does make sense. I have edited my post with it. Thank you.
